# How to replace text with html element for bold, underlined, etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, markdown

I want to implement some simple markdown operations like below snippet in my website. I tried to replace `*` with `<b>` and `**` with `</b>`, then realized that this doesn't work easily in Jquery.

I also realized when writing this snippet, that just the first star is being replaced with `<b>` tag **while nothing replaced in my website with this code**.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#convertBtn").on("click", function () {

        $('#questionDisplay').text($("#questionEdit").val());
        $('#questionDisplay').html($('#questionDisplay').text().replace('**', '</b>'));
        $('#questionDisplay').html($('#questionDisplay').text().replace('*', '<b>')); 
     })       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="questionEdit" rows="5" style="width: 500px;">The user types here many *bold** and *secondBold** texts. The convert button should change the stars to html tags.</textarea>

<button id="convertBtn">Convert</button>
<p>Display: </p>
<p id="questionDisplay"></p>
```

I looked at the similar questions with regEx solutions or any other methods but I didn't understand the work. So, things are:

1. What is the best solution for text to html tag replacement in Jquery?
2. Not for once but for all occurances.
3. And it'd be better if it is possible with only one star wrap like `*boldText*` not two stars at the end. I tried to do this with below code but failed:

`$('#questionDisplay').html($('#questionDisplay').html().replace(/_(.*)__/gi, "<b>$1</b>"));`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `* with <b> and ** with </b>` isn't how markdown works...

Comment: @DanielBeck so how does it work then? I tried to search for a markdown tutorial but didn't find any.

Comment: Well, there's https://www.markdowntutorial.com for starters ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: well it is like just showing the output but it also has the source code. I need a tutorial that teaches how to write the js code. Anyway, I will examine the source code :)

Comment: I was pointing out that the format you describe in the question isn't actually markdown.    If you're doing this out of academic curiosity, that's fine; if you need a real markdown parser I'd suggest using one of the many existing ones rather than rolling your own (I like [this one](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) but there are plenty of others)

Comment: I thought a lot at this subject and finally I decided to write my own because I don't need so much styles, I need the simplicity. However, I don't understand why is this not a markdown. Can you explain it?

Comment: You're using `*this**` for bold.  Markdown uses `*this*` for italics and `**this**` for bold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187516/discussion-between-ninbit-and-daniel-beck).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split` and `join` on `**` and `<b> </b>` respectively. `replace()` will replace the first occurrence only not all the occurrences.

```js
var a;
var b;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#convertBtn").on("click", function () {
$('#questionDisplay').text($("#questionEdit").val());
a=$("#questionDisplay").text();
      $('#questionDisplay').html(a.split("**").join('</b>'));
b=a.split("**").join('</b>');
      $('#questionDisplay').html(b.split('*').join('<b>')); 
      
     })       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="questionEdit" rows="5" style="width: 500px;">The user types here many *bold** and *secondBold** texts. The convert button should change the stars to html tags.</textarea>

<button id="convertBtn">Convert</button>
<p>Display: </p>
<p id="questionDisplay"></p>
```

For single star it gets a bit complicated, we have to use replace as split and join do not understand precedence. So with replace we replace the stars one by one, inside a while loop which runs for the length of the string. The other mechanism of assigning the string to variable remains same.

```js
  var a;
    var b;
    var i=0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#convertBtn").on("click", function () {
    $('#questionDisplay').text($("#questionEdit").val());
    a=$("#questionDisplay").text();
    i=a.length;
    while(i--)
    {
          $('#questionDisplay').html(a.replace("*",'<b>'));
    b=a.replace("*",'<b>');
         $('#questionDisplay').html(b.replace("*",'</b>'));
         a=b.replace("*",'</b>');
          
              
         }
         }) 
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <textarea id="questionEdit" rows="5" style="width: 500px;">The user types here many *bold* and *secondBold* texts. The convert button should change the stars to html tags.</textarea>

    <button id="convertBtn">Convert</button>
    <p>Display: </p>
    <p id="questionDisplay"></p>
```

Comment: Am I the only one who see the same result? It's all bold from `bold` word to the end.

Comment: Just noticed the issue. Sorry. I have edited the answer. You just have to store the changed string into a variable after the first split and join, then perform the split and join on the new variable

Comment: The user types here many *bold** and *secondBold** texts. The convert button should change the stars to html tags.     where??

Comment: Like I stated in the question, both one star before and after the word like `*boldText*`. I try to get rid of the second star at the end only.

Comment: Now, when I add the code for underlined text, the bold tags are removed. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xLnfja0/). How can I solve this? If you want I may open a new post.

Comment: Open a new post please. Solution on this question will confuse everyone

Comment: New post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447426/how-to-replace-text-with-html-element-for-bold-underlined-etc-at-the-same-tim)